# Problem with initializing structure via new operator

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator

Below are two variants of my program

```
struct customer{
    char fullname[35];
    double payment;
};

int main()
{
    customer alex{"Alex", 15};
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
struct customer{
    char fullname[35];
    double payment;
};

int main()
{
    customer* alex = new customer {"Alex", 15};
    return 0;
}
```

The first one works fine, but the second raises `error:could not convert '{"Alex", 15}' from 'brace-enclosed initializer list' to 'customer'`. What's the issue?

Comment: How did you compile it?

Comment: I can't remember at what stage the use of `{...}` for a constructor call came in (thought it was C++11 but maybe it was C++14?) ... you can try enclosing the initializer list in parentheses: `customer* alex = new customer( {"Alex", 15} );` to conform with the 'older' syntax.

Comment: I'm using eclipse IDE(MinGw compiler)

Comment: new customer({"Alex", 15}) ; doesn't work

Comment: You do not have constructor that will take two parameters, that creates confusion. You are invoking default constructor with no parameters.

Comment: plus, even if compiler is "smart" to figure out which parameter is which, you are running into conversion from `std::string` to `c string`.

Comment: This code [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551203/which-of-these-new-expressions-with-char-arrays-are-well-formed) compile. The error is a gcc bug.

Comment: @ciqen why don't they fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I think the code is fine, but some compilers may complain.

Try instead:

```
customer* alex = new auto(customer{"Alex", 15});
```

Comment: this creates object on stack and than invokes copy constructor, doesn't it?

Comment: @0x476f72616e The move constructor, but trivial structs will be constructed in the allocated memory directly. If not by language rules (by one of the many elisions C++ has nowadays), by the optimizer.