# Which of these new expressions with char arrays are well-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, new-operator, c++20

For the following [program](https://godbolt.org/z/1boaGK):

```
int main() 
{
    new char[4] {"text"};  // #1
    new char[5] {"text"};  // #2
    new char[] {"text"};   // #3
}
```

clang gives an error for `#1` which says:

```
error: initializer-string for char array is too long
```

and accepts `#2` and `#3`.

gcc gives the following error for all statements:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
```

and in addition for `#3` it gives the error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
```

So what does the language say about whether this code is well-formed?

I want to know the current rules, but I'd also be interested to know if this has this changed in previous versions of the language.

Comment: You should change the initializer: https://godbolt.org/z/49oe5d

Comment: @Bob__ Sure, thanks, but I'm not really asking for a fix, just whether the code is valid.

Comment: I don't think `#3` is well-formed before C++20 ([Array size deduction in new-expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1009r2.pdf)). Clang supports it but gcc don't (yet) according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's interesting. I think there might be something more going on with the `char` as well. e.g. gcc accepts `new double[5] {1,2,3,4,5};`

Comment: Yeah, and it accepts `new char[4] {'t','e','x','t'};` too

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, but so does clang. I think that's correct, there are only 4 initializers there.

Comment: With the [language-lawyer] tag, you may get a more precise answer if you stated by which C++ Standard you want the statements to be judged.

Comment: @AdrianMole Fair enough, edited.

Comment: From cppreference, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization, a character array of size one less than the size of the string literal is not allowed in C++.

Comment: @crdrisko: Aggregate initialization doesn't apply, since the initializer is a string literal.

Comment: This question may be too deep for my puny brain, but i have no idea what is going on here. You are asking for a `char` array, and trying to shove a string literal in there. They aren't even the same thing. It's like trying to do `new double[5] {"hello"}`. I wish I could think as deeply as you guys do.

Comment: @Andy: "*They aren't even the same thing.*" They're similar enough for C++ to make it legal. It's clear what the user's intent is: to copy the characters of the literal into the array of characters. Why make a user have to write it out manually?

Comment: @NicolBolas -- but since when is "similar enough" a rule in C++? I'm not trying to be pedantic or mean... I'm just trying to understand the question. It should be pretty cut and dry what's going on.

Comment: @Andy Well, beeing pedantic is kind of the point of the language-lawyer tag, so don't worry... Consider those references about the [new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Construction) and [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Character_arrays), even if those don't explain gcc's behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, this is pretty simple to trace. The presence of `{}` means that list initialization is being performed, so we get to visit our favorite part of the spec: [[dcl.init.list]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.list#3).

The object being initialized in case 1 is a `char[4]`. The braced-init-list is not a designated initializer, so 3.1 is ignored. `char[4]` is not a class, so 3.2 is ignored. That [brings us to 3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.list#3.3):

> Otherwise, if `T` is a character array and the initializer list has a single element that is an appropriately-typed string-literal ([dcl.init.string]), initialization is performed as described in that subclause.

Well, `char[4]` is definitely a character array, and the initializer list definitely contains a single element, and that element does in fact match the type of the character array. So off to [[dcl.init.string]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.string) we go.

That tells us (after a fashion):

> Successive characters of the value of the string-literal initialize the elements of the array.

But the next paragraph warns:

> There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements.

Well, that makes #1 ill-formed.

So, we redo the process for `char[5]`. And that doesn't trigger, since 5 is sufficiently large.

Lastly, we come to `char[]`. Which is no different from using a number, as far as initialization is concerned. `char[]` is an array of characters, so it follows the above rules. C++17 would choke on using `char[]` in a `new` expression, but [C++20 is fine with it](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.new#8).

> If the type-id or new-type-id denotes an array type of unknown bound ([dcl.array]), the new-initializer shall not be omitted; the allocated object is an array with n elements, where n is determined from the number of initial elements supplied in the new-initializer ([dcl.init.aggr], [dcl.init.string]).

Which means that #2 and #3 are supposed to be legal. So GCC is wrong to make them ill-formed. And it makes #1 ill-formed for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 1):

Clang is correct in that #1 is ill-formed and #2 is okay.

As Ted Lyngmo noted in a comment, #3 was invalid by the C++ grammar rules, until paper [P1009R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1009r2.pdf) made a change to allow it. A *new-expression* simply did not allow the possiblity of empty `[]` in the type, left over from when there was no syntax to initialize the array created by a *new-expression*, and therefore no way for a compiler to determine the actual size. The paper's changes are accepted in C++20 (but compiler writers will sometimes choose to support "fixes" retroactively in previous `-std=` modes).

For the difference between #1 and #2, the initialization of the array object is specified in [expr.new] to follow the direct-initialization rules of [dcl.init]. The general rules for initialization in [dcl.init] early on say if the initializer is a *braced-init_list*, it is list-initialization. The rules for this in [dcl.init.list] go like:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - [C++20 only:] If the *braced-init-list* contains a *designated-initializer-list*, ...
> - If `T` is an aggregate class and...
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a character array and the initializer list has a single element that is an appropriately-typed *string-literal* ([dcl.init.string]), initialization is performed as described in that subclause.
> - ...

And so [dcl.init.string] ([C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.string), [latest](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.string)) gives the actual initialization rules which apply to this code:

> An array of {C++17: narrow character type}{C++20: ordinary character type ([basic.fundamental])}, `char8_­t` array, `char16_­t` array, `char32_­t` array, or `wchar_­t` array can be initialized by {C++17: a narrow}{C++20: an ordinary} string literal, UTF-8 string literal, UTF-16 string literal, UTF-32 string literal, or wide string literal, respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string-literal enclosed in braces ([lex.string]). Successive characters of the value of the string-literal initialize the elements of the array.
>
> There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> char cv[4] = "asdf";            // error
> ```
>
> is ill-formed since there is no space for the implied trailing `'\0'`. — *end example* ]
>
> If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each element not explicitly initialized shall be zero-initialized ([dcl.init]).

Just like the plain variable definition, when the character array type of a *new-expression* has a specified bound, it must be large enough for all the characters of a string literal initializing it, *including* the trailing null character.

(This is an old difference between C and C++: C does allow `char cv[4] = "asdf";` and ignores the null character.)