# Dynamic character array in C++ initialized with C-style string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to allocate a dynamic array and initialize it with the content "Hello World". The code is as below.

```
char *text = new char[]{"Hello World"};
```

This works perfectly in Visual C++, but throws the below errors in gcc.

```
test.cc:3:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
  char *text = new char[]{"Hello World"};
                        ^
test.cc:3:39: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
  char *text = new char[]{"Hello World"};
                                       ^
```

Need help with the following questions.

1. Is there any known defect in gcc?
2. Shouldn't it work as per the standard?
3. Is Visual C++ Compiler going out of its way to support this?
4. Should this be done differently in gcc?

Comment: Character arrays are more specific to C. In C++, prefer the use of `std::string` to character arrays. It does all the heavy lifting for us.

Comment: I wish I could use ```std::string```, but I have to use a character array

Comment: This question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551203/which-of-these-new-expressions-with-char-arrays-are-well-formed, but would like to retain this question as the existing question's title is not linked to the actual problem and thus doesn't come up in search results